# How to AddMonths in Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I read the date-time Logic App reference, but it has no AddMonths function, as you can see here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#date-and-time-functions

Currently the function used is AddDays(-30) and it "failed" in 2022-03-01.
It reached 2022-01-30 because February/2022 has just 28 days.

How can I solve it?

Comment: What does "failed" mean ?  2022-01-30 is is 30 days before 2022-03-01

Comment: @Hogstrom I typed "failed" in quotes. It failed to the business rule. the developer that did it( using AddDay function) thought that the result should came back a month

Comment: What is the output you want ?  That will help understand how to get you there

Comment: I already figured out how to do it (as my own answer below to this question).
In the documentation has a function ( subtractFromTime ) that solves it, you need to do something like subtractFromTime(getdate(), -1,'Month')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is function called `subtractFromTime`, it works fine.